# noCompress "tflite" does not work with noCompress "pb"

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I use tensorflow mobile and lite on Android,assets contains model.pb and model2.tflite,build.gradle:

```
android {
     ...
     aaptOptions {
         noCompress "tflite"
         noCompress "pb"
     }
}

dependencies {
     ...
     implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.13.1'
     implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.1.0'
     implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.1.0'
}
```

When I run this code:

```
val fileDescriptor = context.assets.openFd(modelFile)
```

console logs:`java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`,pb is work.
When I remove `noCompress "pb"`,tflite is work.
device: simulator Android10 and Samsung8 9
Why,Can you help me?Thank you.

Comment: move pb files to the raw directory and remove noCompress "pb" is a temporary solution